# If $\langle v,v\rangle_1\leq\langle v,v\rangle_2$, is the completion with respect to $2$ a subset of the completion with respect to $1$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be a complex vector space with two inner products $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\, \rangle_1$ and $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\, \rangle_2$ and suppose
$$\langle v,v\rangle_1\leq\langle v,v\rangle_2$$
for all $v\in V$. In addition, let $H_i$ be the completion of $V$ with respect to $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\, \rangle_i$.

Is it true that we can identify $H_2$ with a subset of $H_1$?

[In the paper that I'm reading](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/david.reutter/AtiyahSinger_Essay.pdf) it is claimed that $H_2\subset H_1$ for the reason stated above in proposition 2.3 on page 33.

Comment: Certainly Cauchy sequences with respect to $\| \cdot \|_2$ are Cauchy with respect to $\| \cdot \|_1$. Is that enough of an "identification"? I doubt there'll be an isometric embedding of one completion in another.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for your comment! [In the paper that I'm reading](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/david.reutter/AtiyahSinger_Essay.pdf) it is claimed that $H_2\subset H_1$ in proposition 2.3 on page 33.